# Create a vdx file from scratch using aspose.diagram

Tags: c#, visio, aspose

Creating a diagram is okay, and then a page can be added.

But after that, the main issue come from adding master; isn't there any possible way to add a master from scratch without using the VSS (any stencil) and using  [Aspose.Diagrams](http://docs.aspose.com:8082/docs/display/diagramnet/Home) instead?

Comment: You cannot create a master from scratch. It is possible to add master from other Visio diagrams or stencils. Post your detail scenario in Aspose.Diagram forums, the support will help you. http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/aspose.diagram-product-family/489/showforum.aspx

Comment: thanks,
One more thing, How to add container and add other shapes to it,
i tried but, couldn't find any examples

Comment: Please check http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/diagramnet/Glue+Visio+Shapes+Together+with+Connection+Point and http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/diagramnet/Glue+Shapes+Inside+the+Container. See if the sample code there helps

Answer (score 1):

After going through the [**aspose forum**](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/aspose.diagram-product-family/489/showforum.aspx), only way to add master is using predefined Stencil,

Using visio, create a stencl, with all the required shapes/ masters, and add those to the new visio instance, and manipulate

Answer (score -1):

@Biswajeet,
Aspose.Diagram API now allows to create a master from scratch without any Visio stencil, drawing or template. Please check this code example: [Create Master from Scratch](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/diagramjava/Working+with+Masters#WorkingwithMasters-CreateMasterfromScratch)

I work as a Developer Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: Please keep your answer self-contained and provide code samples within the answer. Linking to external material for *more supporting* content is fine, but not having and substantial content within the answer itself is not.